# Can't get auto generated signalr/hubs js file

Tags: signalr, windows-8.1, iis-8, virtual-directory

I've set up 2 sites in IIS. This is the structure:

```
Application Pools
Sites
  -> LogService.WebUI (port 80)
       -> assets
       -> bin
       -> Service References
       -> notifications (virtual app)
  -> LogService.Notifications (port 81)
       -> bin
       -> Scripts
```

The notifications virtual app in the WebUI site and the LogService.Notifications site both point to the same physical location. When I view

```
http://localhost:80/notifications/signalr/hubs
```

I get a 404 Not Found error. When I view

```
http://localhost:81/signalr/hubs
```

I see the auto-generated signalr js script.

I've also tried adding this to the config file

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

When this project is deployed it will be a virtual directory. How can I get it to point to the correct location? I've looked at tons of examples, but none that have worked so far.

Comment: LogService.Notifications running in the same app pool as LogService.WebUI?

Comment: @halter73 - Yes, they are in the same app pool.